# What are the risks in staking through my MM address?

Tags: blockchain, metamask, chainlink, staking

Long story short my MM address is eligible for the Chainlink staking program that would lock my tokens into a smart contract on Ethereum for 1 year.

The concern I'm having is, because the address has not been created using a cold wallet, it has ( in my mind ) a lot more open doors for being attacked. Is this worry unfounded since the tokens will be locked in a smart contract anyway? The logic being, even if my address is hacked, the attacker will not be able to transfer the tokens since they are locked.

Are there other vectors of attack I should be concerned with, or maybe something I can do to decrease the chance of a successful attack ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this worry unfounded since the tokens will be locked in a smart contract anyway?

There is a risk.

If the private key of the wallet has leaked e.g. due to poor cybersecurity hygiene, then anyone who has a copy of the private key can race to unstake and steal your assets when they unlock.